# Adding code to a model with a custom rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have written a simple blog plugin (it's actually a rails engine).  It is designed to be installed into an app that already has a user model set up.

In order to save me from having to open up my User model and manually inserting "has_many :posts", I'd like to write a rake task that automatically does this for me.

If I were to package my engine as a generator inside a gem, then the following would probably work:

```
def manifest
  record do |m|     
    m.insert_into "app/models/user.rb", 'has_many :posts'
  end
end
```

Can this kind of thing be done with from a rake task?  I've look around and I can't find an answer...  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you include a model file in your plugin that would open up the User class and add the "has_many :posts"?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end
```

I think that would work because you can open Ruby classes at any time and from any file; so no matter if the project using your plugin has a user.rb file in his model folder, you file will also be loaded and the has_many will be added to the User class at runtime.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely access your model through a rake task. You have to be sure to pass it your environment though so that it knows about your models. For example,

```
desc"This will insert the Posts"

task(:insertPosts => :environment) do

#your code here

end
```

Comment: Hi Sosborn, thanks for your advice.  The solution to this particular problem was to include a user.rb file inside the plugin (as advised by Juan) so that the usre.rb file which is already present in the application prior to plugin installation is extended with extra functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a task where actually modifying the source is appropriate? Have you considered including a module? Please give further details of what you're trying to achieve for correct guidance.

Comment: Hi Steve.  I will look into this idea of using a module.  For now the solution provided by Juan works.